# Use image as WPF Button icon mask?

Tags: wpf, icons

I'd like to know if it's possible to do the following:

- create a black and white image, say of a dog
- add the image to a button as a mask
- change the style using (data) triggers, e.g. disabled - the dog is grey, "loading" - the dog is red, "ready" the dog is yellow, etc.

Basically I want to create button icons using pixels but be able to set the color at runtime depending on triggers. Something like this:

[image: dog buttons]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After 2 hours of googling here's the answer

```
<Window x:Class="IconTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- button style -->
        <Style x:Key="ToolButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Width="16" Height="16" Background="#ffbbbbbb">
                            <Rectangle Name="rect" Fill="Black" OpacityMask="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="rect" Property="Fill" Value="Green" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="rect" Property="Fill" Value="Yellow" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Width="16" Height="16" Style="{StaticResource ToolButton}">
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/test.png"/>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define an `OpacityMask` for the `Button`. I believe you will be able to add triggers (if you need them) to change the `Background` of Button.

[image]

**Sample:**

```
<Button Height="100" Width="100" Background="Green">
    <Button.OpacityMask>
    <DrawingBrush AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Top">
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <DrawingGroup>
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#33000000">
            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,40,40" />
            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
            </GeometryDrawing>
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF000000">
            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="10,10,20,20">
                <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="45" CenterX="20" CenterY="20" />
                </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                </RectangleGeometry>
            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
            </GeometryDrawing>
        </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    </DrawingBrush>
    </Button.OpacityMask>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you don't need create image mask in WPF to achieve your requirement.  You could simply edit the control template of the button class.

Please refer to the **Ellipse button example** in this page. [Control Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.aspx)

Then you could simply change the Fill Color of that shape using trigger. [Trigger](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-2-WPF_Styles__Triggers.aspx)

Cheers,

Comment: I need to use an image to set the icon since I'm needing more than geometric shapes.